# given a list in python, add a number to each entry

Tags: python

**UPDATE #3 : recording the answer**

Used the following code here:

```
l = ['idXchgTradeID', 'quantity', 'price', 'commission', 'commasset', 'xchgTradeID', 'status']
   
output = '(' + ",".join([f"{v} =:{i+1}" for i, v in enumerate( l )]).upper() + ')'

print(output)
```

**and it worked. The output is as follows:**

```
(IDXCHGTRADEID =:1,QUANTITY =:2,PRICE =:3,COMMISSION =:4,COMMASSET =:5,XCHGTRADEID =:6,STATUS =:7)
```

**ORIGINAL ENTRY (with further clarification)**

I have the following:

```
   # PROCESS THE "SET" CLAUSE  of the UPDATE
        sql_vals  = []; sql_cols = []; sql_inputs = [];

        # split dictionary into keys and values
        sql_cols, sql_inputs = zip(*set_data['set'].items())

        # did this part just to look for an answer
        for count, row in enumerate(sql_cols, start=1):
                 sql_vals.append( count )


        print(  sql_cols )
        print(  sql_inputs )

        res = { sql_cols[i]: sql_vals[i] for i in range(len(sql_cols)) }
        print( res)

        exit()
```

The answers I am getting are:

```
('idXchgTradeID', 'quantity', 'price', 'commission', 'commasset', 'xchgTradeID', 'status')
('binancexcgid', 0.0018, 28.0, 0.0021, 'BTC', '483494384', 'FILLED')
```

This is similar to what I am seeking as a final:

```
{'idXchgTradeID': 1, 'quantity': 2, 'price': 3, 'commission': 4, 'commasset': 5, 'xchgTradeID': 6, 'status': 7}
```

I am looking for something like:

```
{'idXchgTradeID' = :1, 'quantity' = :2, 'price' = :3, 'commission' = :4, 'commasset' =:5, 'xchgTradeID' =:6, 'status' =:7}
```

It is supposed to be used as part of an input to Oracle (as seen in the example below)

```
cur = con.cursor()
statement = 'update cx_people set age = :1 where id = :2'
cur.execute(statement, (31, 1))
con.commit()
```

Comment: It is not clear (to me) at all what your desired output is. Is that supposed to be valid python?

Comment: Perhaps you just want [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) e.g. `(i+1, v) for i, v in enumerate(t)`

Comment: What does `= :1` etc. indicate in your required output?

Comment: @MarkMeyer - reread the post. It says "I am looking for something like: ..." Also, see the code below. it is the way Oracle is expecting one to send in the SQL statement for a type of "query by parameter" scenario. So, in essence, I am seeking to convert a Python dictionary representation so that it will work with Oracle. It will not look like basic python. TIA

Comment: @khelwood - thanks for the response. I made changes to the post. Regards

Comment: Are you just looking for a string?? Like `"idXchgTradeID = :1, quantity = :2, price = :3"`? It would save you a lot of time just to say so. If so, you can: `", ".join([f"{v} =:{i+1}" for i, v in enumerate(some_list)])`

Comment: @MikeMeyer - yes, I am looking for a string. I will attempt to use the suggestion you have provided.

Comment: @MikeMeyer - thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you'd like something like the `enumerate` function. This provides a list of each item in the list with its index

```
l = ['idXchgTradeID', 'quantity', 'price', 'commission', 'commasset', 'xchgTradeID', 'status']

for index,s in enumerate(l):
    print(s,index+1)
```

Output

```
idXchgTradeID 1
quantity 2
price 3
commission 4
commasset 5
xchgTradeID 6
status 7
```

If the numbers are not necessarily in order, it seems that you are looking for a `Dictionary`. This data structure maps from a key to data points.

```
d = {
'idXchgTradeID':1, 
'quantity':2, 
'price':3, 
'commission':4, 
'commasset':5, 
'xchgTradeID':6, 
'status':7
}

for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Output

```
idXchgTradeID 1
quantity 2
price 3
commission 4
commasset 5
xchgTradeID 6
status 7
```